Configure two network cards persistently
I have two NICs and want to set the system up so the second one is the main/default one.

First one is a 1Gb unit and its built into.
The second one which is a 2.5gb NIC is attached over USB3, this one I did not have when I installed the OS, which is - Raspberry Pi OS Lite 64-bit Debian version: 12 (bookworm)

All I want to do or rather wish to archive is setting the 2.5Gb one as the main/default one! Is this possible?
Every time I set this up using nmtui it works while system is still on, but if and when the system is rebooted I have to do it all over again.

These posts/threats showing all the rabbit holes I have gone into and what I have attempted and ultimately failed solve the situation..
Raspberry Pi Forums - Raspberry Pi Forums
Update, I post the command and the result here, and thank you @metablaster for aiding me through all this!
sudo nano /etc/systemd/network/lo.network

[Match]
Name=lo
Type=loopback

[Network]
Address=127.0.0.1/8

sudo nano /etc/systemd/network/eth0.network

[Match]
Name=eth0
Type=ether

[Network]
DHCP=yes

[DHCPv4]
RouteMetric=100

sudo nano /etc/systemd/network/eth1.network

[Match]
Name=eth1
Type=ether

[Address]
Address=10.0.0.10/24
Broadcast=true
RouteMetric=10

[Network]
DHCP=no
DNS=1.1.1.1

[Route]
Gateway=10.0.0.1
Metric=10

ls -1 /etc/systemd/network

73-usb-net-by-mac.link
99-default.link
eth0.network
eth1.network
lo.network

sudo systemctl status networking

○ networking.service - Raise network interfaces
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; disabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:interfaces(5)

sudo systemctl status systemd-networkd

● systemd-networkd.service - Network Configuration
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-04-28 14:24:11 CEST; 7h ago
TriggeredBy: ● systemd-networkd.socket
       Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
             man:org.freedesktop.network1(5)
   Main PID: 314 (systemd-network)
     Status: "Processing requests..."
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9255)
        CPU: 90ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-networkd.service
             └─314 /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd

Apr 28 14:24:11 Pi5 systemd-networkd[314]: eth0: Configuring with /etc/systemd/network/eth0.network.
Apr 28 14:24:11 Pi5 systemd[1]: Started systemd-networkd.service - Network Configuration.
Apr 28 14:24:11 Pi5 systemd-networkd[314]: lo: Configuring with /etc/systemd/network/lo.network.
Apr 28 14:24:11 Pi5 systemd-networkd[314]: eth0: Link UP
Apr 28 14:24:41 Pi5 systemd-networkd[314]: eth1: found matching network '/etc/systemd/network/eth1.network', based on potentially unpredictable interface name.
Apr 28 14:24:41 Pi5 systemd-networkd[314]: eth1: Configuring with /etc/systemd/network/eth1.network.
Apr 28 14:24:41 Pi5 systemd-networkd[314]: eth1: Link UP
Apr 28 14:24:44 Pi5 systemd-networkd[314]: eth1: Gained carrier
Apr 28 14:24:44 Pi5 systemd-networkd[314]: eth1: found matching network '/etc/systemd/network/eth1.network', based on potentially unpredictable interface name.
Apr 28 14:24:46 Pi5 systemd-networkd[314]: eth1: Gained IPv6LL

ethtool eth1

Settings for eth1:
        Supported ports: [ TP    MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
                                2500baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
                                2500baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                             1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 32
        Transceiver: internal
netlink error: Operation not permitted
        Current message level: 0x00007fff (32767)
                               drv probe link timer ifdown ifup rx_err tx_err tx_queued intr tx_done rx_status pktdata hw wol
        Link detected: yes

ip route show

default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth1 proto static metric 10
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.10 metric 10

ip addr show

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2c:cf:67:2f:cf:9a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:24:27:88:29:17 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.10/24 metric 10 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd75:a6e1:4b04:360:224:27ff:fe88:2917/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 1552sec preferred_lft 1552sec
    inet6 fe80::224:27ff:fe88:2917/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager
sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager
sudo systemctl status NetworkManager

○ NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; disabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)


It's unclear whether you're having those 2 NIC's on a Debian 12 system or Raspberry Pi or does each system has one NIC and what one system has to do with the other, please clarify this in your question. please lay out your network topology if possible.

Please edit your post with the output of cat /etc/network/interfaces then it should be possible to explain how to modify this file for the system to prefer one NIC over the other.

You have 2 NIC's and want the 2.5gb NIC to be the default one and prefered over the 1Gb one.
In addition to that according to cat /etc/network/interfaces output in your comment this is possible only with systemd-networkd
What this means is that networking service needs to be disabled (if it's enabled) and systemd-networkd should be used instead.
systemd-networkd provides a method to configure interfaces and most importantly to set interface metric which will make one of the NIC's the default one.
First step is to learn NIC names by running the following command:
ip link show

This command will list your NIC names, example output for single NIC is below:
6: ovsbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e6:db:3f:88:4b:48 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.11.1/24 brd 192.168.11.255 scope global ovsbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::e4db:3fff:fe88:4b48/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

In this example ovsbr0 is NIC name, in your actual output you should see multiple NIC names but you only care about the 2 NIC's which you need to configure, including the lo NIC which is loopback interface and needs to be configured as well.
Let's first configure lo interface as follows:
sudo nano /etc/systemd/network/lo.network

This will open up nano editor, insert (copy\paste) the following configuration into it and save with CTRL+O and CTRL+X:
[Match]
Name=lo
Type=loopback

[Network]
Address=127.0.0.1/8

loopback interface is configured, next you need to configure your other 2 NIC's, the configuration of each NIC is stored in /etc/systemd/network directory.
A file that is created should be named after NIC name with *.network extension like we did with lo interface above.
I'm going to assume your NIC's are called enp1 and enp2 but you make sure to replace those names with your actual NIC names obtained by ip link show command.
I'm also going to assume the enp1 is your 2.5gb NIC which you want to be the default one...
So config of the first one goes:
sudo nano /etc/systemd/network/enp1.network

Config for this NIC goes:
[Match]
Name=enp1

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4

[DHCPv4]
RouteMetric=10

[Route]
Metric=10

That's it, save the config and close nano editor then we configure the second one:
sudo nano /etc/systemd/network/enp2.network

Config for this NIC goes:
[Match]
Name=enp2

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4

[DHCPv4]
RouteMetric=100

[Route]
Metric=100

Save and close nano editor again.
Notice that RouteMetric entry determines which NIC will be the default one, lower metric means higher priority!
Next we need to disable networking service as follows (if error, ignore it)
# Backup previous config
sudo mv /etc/network/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces.save

# Stop networking
sudo systemctl stop networking
sudo systemctl disable networking

Next step is to enable systemd-networkd service (must succeed):
# Start systemd-networkd
sudo systemctl start systemd-networkd
sudo systemctl enable systemd-networkd

Verify systemd-networkd is enabled and networking disabled from the output:
sudo systemctl status networking
sudo systemctl status systemd-networkd

Finally reboot system:
systemctl reboot

After performing these steps upon reboot the 2.5gb NIC should be used by default.
system has rebooted...
Check routing is correct:
ip route show

It should show that your enp1 NIC has metric assigned to 10 for the default route, for instance:
default via x.x.x.x dev enp1 proto static metric 10
default via x.x.x.x dev enp2 proto static metric 100

Check DHCP works and IP was assigned:
ip addr show

Should show that enp1 has obtained an IPv4 address from your NAT router.
For instance:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Under inet section it shows address was assigned, if thre is no inet address it doesn't work.

Updated the post with the results, the metric din't stick/worked. I rechecked everything, can't say I see something being missed by me. I check again!

@Assarelius Your output looks OK, the eth1 interface obtained an address and is sticking to the configured metric of 100, and the reason why eth0 NIC does not get an IP and metric of 10 is likely because it's not connected to network, make sure to connect it with LAN cable to your router or gateway. does it obtain IP and metric of 10 when you do so?

ok, I have connected both NIC's to my network and got IP for both NIC's the output for ip route show I did put and update in my questions/original post. Maybe it dose not matter but the metric is 100, 101? I have gone over every step in your post (now checked again) and cant figure out what I missed/what is causing this.

@Assarelius I have edited my post, basically add [Route] Metric= section, to the 2 files for eth0 and eth1, see post. then to apply with sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd the NIC with lower metric should be the 2.5G one. then run ip route again to confirm it works.

I tried, I think I got it, did update my post again, but maybe I missed something, sudo systemctl status systemd-networkd seems like something is amiss no?

@Assarelius looks perfect and as it should look like, metric 10 and 100 was assigned to routes as configured, the NIC with metric of 10 is the default now, the only problem is that your eth0 interface has 2 routes somehow, I think system reboot should handle that. if not then disconnect eth0 and reconnect it. if still not working delete route with ip route del default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0 followed by sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd

@Assarelius and the message which says based on potentially unpredictable interface name is to be expected because your OS doesn't name NIC's based on PCI? bus which might result in issues if both NIC's are used but that's rare scenario. to handle that see docs here: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.network.html and here https://wiki.debian.org/SystemdNetworkd and here https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkInterfaceNames good luck!

‘pi@Pi5:~ $ sudo ip route del default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0
RTNETLINK answers: No such process’ also did the restart but that didn’t have the effect though

@Assarelius, try this sudo ip route del default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0 metric 101

This is weird tbh, got the same again, ‘RTNETLINK answers: No such process’

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

For a clearer output of ip command, depending on the specific information you need, you can use the option -br (br[ief]). So if you need only the names of the interfaces: ip -br link show.

I need to add the fact that NetworkManager is also disabled in order to get above answer/solution to work properly. sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager and then sudo systemctl disable NetworkManagerand lastley check status using sudo systemctl status NetworkManager ○ NetworkManager.service - Network Manager      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; disabled; preset: enabled)      Active: inactive (dead)        Docs: man:NetworkManager(8) 
